# String var assigned to view-state?

Tags: viewstate, spring-webflow

I am not sure if this is possible in webflow 2.2.1

**flow.xml**

```
<view-state id="flowId1" model="flowModel1" view="/WEB-INF/templates/Flow_Form/form1.jsp">
    <set attribute="strVar" value="${'someStringVar'}" />       
    <transition on="step1" to="step1Action" />
</view-state>
```

**jsp**

```
<h1>${strVar}</h1>
```

Essentially, I'd like to assign a String var that will change value accross individual view-states, that is set in the flow.xml..

Are there any other simple recommended approaches to this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

got it.. :)

```
<view-state id="flowId1" model="flowModel1" view="/WEB-INF/templates/Flow_Form/form1.jsp">
    <on-entry>
            <evaluate expression="'someStringVar'" result="flowScope.strVar"/>
        </on-entry>     
    <transition on="step1" to="step1Action" />
</view-state>
```